# Firefox on Android, "Save to PDF" -- where does the PDF go?

Tags: firefox-for-android

I am using the steps [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/save-page-pdf-firefox-android).

But... nothing happens, and when I troll around the file system, I do not spot any new pdf.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The page is downloaded as a PDF in your preferred download location, which by-default is the directory named Download under Internal Storage. When successful, a notification is shown that the page has been downloaded and it can also be seen through Tools > Downloads section within Firefox.

If you do not give Storage permission to Firefox, Firefox confuses the user when trying to save a page. When my Firefox didn't have Storage permission and I tried to save a page, it just did nothing, as in no UI response.

Comment: >> When my Firefox didn't have Storage permission and I tried to save a page, it just did nothing, as in no UI response. --- that is probably what is happening to me.